# Copy tensor elements of certain indices in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tensor, torch, indices

The desired operation is similar in spirit to `torch.Tensor.index_copy`, but a little different.

It's best explained with an example.

Tensor `A` has original values that we will copy:

`[10, 20, 30]`

Tensor `B` has indices of `A`:

`[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1]`

Tensor `C` has same length as `B`, containing the indexed values of `A`:

`[10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 20]`

What's a good way to make `C` from `A` and `B` in PyTorch, without using loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just indexing by A?

```
In [1]: import torch
  
In [2]: a = torch.tensor([20,30,40])

In [3]: b = torch.tensor([0,1,2,1,1,2,0,0,1,2])

In [4]: a[b]
Out[4]: tensor([20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 40, 20, 20, 30, 40])
```

Comment: I think that'll do it. And I can still do autograd on that output tensor?

Comment: I think so, but can't answer for certain sorry.